# Blocked windshield washer jet 96 Suburban K2500

Tags: chevrolet, windshield-washer, gmc

The passenger side washer jet on my 96 GMC Suburban K2500 got something in it, and I can't figure out how to clear it. The tubing is buried somewhere inside the firewall and I can't find the end to backflush it. Any suggestions?

Comment: The tubing is going to end at the reservoir.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, washer jets tend to clog at the actual jet - first thing I'd do is get a thin needle and try to clear the jet itself.